# Spring Boot can't find any JDBC repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm having an issue with my Spring Boot application with MySQL JDBC.
When I'm starting the application, it says as following:

```
2023-01-08T09:21:01.662+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 116 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-01-08T09:21:02.325+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-08T09:21:02.982+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@50f29d33
2023-01-08T09:21:02.985+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-08T09:21:03.262+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-01-08T09:21:03.293+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [  restartedMain] .BandwichPersistenceDebuggingApplication : Started BandwichPersistenceDebuggingApplication in 3.592 seconds (process running for 4.993)
2023-01-08T09:21:03.307+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-01-08T09:21:03.420+01:00  INFO 17736 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Then the application stops.

First it said that there wasn't any url descriped, afterwards I inserted it into the property file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
server-port=8081
```

... is with my own information.

I have a datasource with a successful connection.

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>laustrup</groupId>
<artifactId>BandwichPersistenceDebugging</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>BandwichPersistenceDebugging</name>
<description>BandwichPersistenceDebugging</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>18</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Standard spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Additional -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I'm having a package setup like this:

[image]

It's in red, since it is not added to git.

Hope that anyone has seen this before and has a solution, feel free to add if some information is missing.

Comment: how is your `SpringBootApplication` configured?

Comment: Why should it be an issue? Your repositories are classes and not interfaces, the message indicates that SPring Data JDBC doesn't find any repositories. There is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line.

```xml
   <scope>runtime</scope>
```

You can see the documentation detail in here:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope

Hope that helps.